# Non-negative Constraints in Soft-Margin SVM Lagrange Equation

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm, lagrange-multipliers

I was reading the [A Tutorial on Support Vector Machines for Pattern Recognition](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Emallat/papiers/svmtutorial.pdf) as a supplemental for my
Intro to ML class and I wasn't sure why $ a_i \geq 0 $ and $ \lambda_i \geq 0 $ cannot be negative in this case. Can they be negative for any other similar types of optimization problems?

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\min \frac{1}{2} ||w||^2 + \frac{C}{n}\sum_i \xi_i +
\sum_i \alpha_i (1-y_i w^T x_i - \xi_i) - \sum_i \lambda_i \xi_i \\
\alpha_i \geq 0, \xi_i \geq 0, \lambda_i \geq 0
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly since this is the [Langragian dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)) - dual variables must be non-negative.